# WinSock can not connect

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I've just started to learn WinSock. 
I started by reading this article: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530750(v=vs.85).aspx
And i did what I was wrote to do.

But I can not connect, every time I run this program i got same error:

> Connection timed out.
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.

My code is here:
http://pastebin.com/0THqWKXv

Could you tell me what did I wrong? How to repair my code?

PS.
The IP adress is to google.pl

PS2.
Actual code responsible for connection:

```
iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
while (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout << "Blad ustanowienia polaczenia:\t" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    ptr = ptr->ai_next;
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);

}
```

Comment: Is there anything listening on the other side?

Comment: i hope that google is listening, em I wrong :D ?

Comment: for example i would like to download index.html from some www

Comment: What is port? As I see from your source it's 27015 which is "standard" only for CS yet google still can't play CS ;-)

Comment: @Piwniczne Why would Google be listening on port 27015?

Comment: changed to 80 and still the same. 

#define DEFAULT_PORT "80" ;/

Comment: may it be caused by my router?

Comment: OMG. I've changed addres from IP to "www.google.com" and it seems to work o.O

Answer (score 0):

You should call `getaddrinfo()` to resolve the address before calling `connect()`:

```
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(addr, nPort, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) 
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) 
    {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
```

Comment: Didn't help- the same problem as before.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed addres to "google.com" and port to "80" and it works. 
Thanks a lot!